# How to change the position of placeholder text in Material-UI React input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI with React and I have an input component with a placeholder text that appears at the end instead of the beginning.

I tried searching the Material-UI documentation, specifically in the InputLabel section (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-label/), but I couldn't find a solution for this issue. I also created a demo in CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lake-bbopn4?file=/demo.tsx) to demonstrate the problem.

How can I change the position of the placeholder text to appear at the beginning of the input field using Material-UI? If this is not possible with Material-UI, what would be the best way to achieve this using CSS or JavaScript?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Input } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const periods = [
    { key: "", value: "הכל" },
    { key: "0-1", value: "חודש" },
    { key: "1-3", value: "1-3 חודשים" },
    { key: "3-6", value: "3-6 חודשים" }
  ];

  return (
    <Box sx={{ direction: "rtl", textAlign: "start" }}>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="period-filter-label">מיין לפי תקופה</InputLabel>
        <Select
          style={{ width: "300px" }}
          labelId="period-filter-label"
          id="period-filter"
          value={""}
          label="מיין לפי תקופה"
          onChange={(event) => {}}
        >
          {periods.map((item, key) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={key} value={item?.key}>
                {item.value}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl style={{ marginRight: "30px", textAlign: "start" }}>
        <InputLabel id="interest-type-label3">סכום שברצונך להפקיד</InputLabel>
        <Input
          id="interest-type"
          type="number"
          value={""}
          onChange={(event) => {}}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the rest of your page left-to-right and this is just a single right-to-left component that exists with within it or is the entire page right-to-left?

Comment: The entire website is right-to-left. You can see it at https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lake-bbopn4?file=/index.tsx:287-356.

Comment: @MosheFortgang have you read the example here https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/#demo ?

Comment: @VladVladov Thanks I tried it when I first opened the question, but apparently I didn't do it correctly. Now I tried again and it did solve my problem.